# How to find percentage for each distinct value that meet a certain condition in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There are three columns: ID, date, sleeptimehrs. I want to find the percentage of days where each ID had more than 7 hours of sleep. So for example ID "10" has 15 days/rows of data. 7 of those rows are less than 7 hours in "sleeptimehrs" and 8 rows are more than 7 hours. I want the output to be a table where it says ID: 10, Percent: 53.33% for all the IDs.

I tried doing CASE WHEN Sleeptimerhrs >= 7 or COUNT(DISTINCT IF(sleeptimehrs >=7))

I know these are pretty incorrect so im looking for some guidance on how to do this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a derived table that counts the days as needed for the percentage calculation, then present that calculation:

```
SELECT
      ID
    , sleep7 * 100.0 / alldays * 1.0 AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT
          ID
        , count(CASE WHEN Sleeptimerhrs >= 7 THEN 1 END) AS sleep7
        , count(*) AS alldays
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY
          ID
    ) derived
```

**nb** aggregation functions such as count ignore NULL so the **case expression** only needs to return a non-null value when the criteria is met.

Comment: Thank you! That query was simpler than I thought, but I dont understand what the ```THEN 1 END``` part does after ```CASE WHEN``` and I'm also confused on how ```count(*)``` counts alldays for each unique ID, like how does it know that ID "10" has 15 days or ID "11" has 17 days.

Comment: COUNT() literally counts rows. `COUNT(*)` will count all rows, `count(CASE WHEN Sleeptimerhrs >= 7 THEN 1 END)` will only count the 1's and will ignore any rows that are  therefore`Sleeptimerhrs < 7`. The "magic" is the `GROUP BY ID` which means all theses calculations are done **per ID**

Comment: `THEN 1`  simply returns the value 1 IF the condition is met. Alternatives could be: `count(CASE WHEN Sleeptimerhrs >= 7 THEN '7 or more' END)` or like this: `count(CASE WHEN Sleeptimerhrs >= 7 THEN Sleeptimerhrs END)`  all the **case expression** needs to do is return some non-null value and that non-null value will then be counted.